# Heteromino: Introduction

Tags: grid-deduction

**Heteromino** is an area-dividing puzzle with very simple rules. I encountered this puzzle type on [puzz.link](https://puzz.link), and seeing there's none posted here, I decided to give it a try.

Here is an example puzzle with solution:

[image] [image]

The rules of Heteromino are as follows:

1. Divide the white area into L- or I-trominoes.
2. No two trominoes of identical shape and orientation may share an edge.

Now, solve the following puzzle:

[image]

Comment: Ooh this puzzle type is kinda memorable for me.. In my previous uni, I tried to prove that this is NP-hard :)

Comment: @athin Interesting. Did you complete the proof?

Comment: Fortunately yes, we were planning to rewrite the proof in English (because it was written in Indonesian haha), but until now we haven't continued it.. XD

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First:

> Take a look at the cell in row 2, column 3. It must be part of a region extending left -- where is the third cell in that region? If it goes left, it blocks off 2 cells in the upper left. If it goes down, then there will be two Γ-trominoes adjacent. So it must go up.
>
>  [image]
>
>  Similarly, the group with cell R3C2 now cannot go down or right, so it must go left.
>
>  [image]

Similar logic, but with a bit of lookahead:

> If the group with cell R4C3 goes right, then the bottom will either be two — shapes, or a ⅂ shape that touches the one we already have. So it must go down.
>
>  [image]
>
>  Another bit of lookahead gives us this: If we have this pink-highlighted box, there's a problem in the upper right. (Either two ⅃ shapes touch, or we block off a cell in the right column.)
>
>  [image]
>  Extending the top region rightwards is also an issue...
>  [image]
>
>  so we have this:
>  [image]
>  [image]

Finishing off the puzzle with some more attacks on carefully-chosen borders:

> [image]
>  This is impossible (because it will either make two |-shaped regions, or a 4-long region in the bottom.)
>  [image]
>  And then the two remaining cells in row 4 must be connected (to not have two |-shaped regions touching), and that finishes off the puzzle!
>  [image]

Comment: Super fast and nice job, as always :) My logic for the top right region was that rot13(vs E1P4 vf n ubevmbagny V, nyy guerr pubvprf sbe E3P4 yrnq gb pbagenqvpgvbaf).

Comment: @Bubbler Makes sense! I figured that out early on (not completely rigorously), before actually starting with the top left. But since it didn't immediately lead anywhere, I wanted to see if I could find a simpler logical path through the puzzle.

Comment: Thank, this really helps!